# Pin Unlock Screen React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, lockscreen, passcode

Does React-Native community has any package or custom implementation that provides custom Pin/Passcode Unlock Overlay Screen like Default Android/iOS device unlocks screen without opening Keyboard.

Ref Images:

[Android Unlock Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEHbg.png)

[iOS Unlock Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fyhs.jpg)